# lede open vpn vlan routing

Tags: routing, openvpn, vlan, ping

Hope someone can help me, I have a LinkSys WRT1900 ACS v2 router on which i have installed LEDE. I have 2 vlans (192.165.5.1/24, 192.168.10.1/24), I have also OpenVPN setup and my goal was to have traffic from 1 vlan (.10.1) routed through VPN and traffic from the other vlan (.5.1) not go though VPN.

I have this working in so many words, but for the non vpn vlan to connect to the internet, i have had to add the following as a start up script

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table 10
ip rule add from 192.168.5.2 table 10
ip rule add from 192.168.5.3 table 10
ip....
```

The above works fine, one vlan goes via VPN and the other not through VPN, the only issue with this is that the moment i put the above code for each ip address and reboot my router for the changes to take affect, i can no longer ping between vlans, and i really would like to connect to devices locally on either vlan.

If i take out the table above, I dont get internet on non VPN VLAN, but can ping devices on both vlans locally.

if it helps, i have added some further info for you below.

OpenVPN Config File

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote *****OMITTED*****
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0

explicit-exit-notify 3

remote-cert-tls server

#mute 10000
auth-user-pass secret

comp-lzo
verb 3
pull
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512

<ca>
*****OMITTED*****
</ca>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
*****OMITTED*****
</tls-auth>
```

Router IP Routing Table

```
root@LEDE:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1.2
10.8.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tun0
89.34.98.194    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1.2
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1.2
192.168.0.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1.2
192.168.5.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-VLAN5
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-VLAN10
root@LEDE:~#
```

Any help would really be appreciated, and please take it easy on me as i am rather new to all this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about routing, not about using a VPN or VLANs (but the integration with the VPN can certainly add difficulty).

- About the main issue: communication between LANs

The table 10 is in use for IPs from `192.168.5.0/24`, so when such an IP gets the default route, this route will be used for *any* destination, including other LANs' IPs even if that's not intended. So it has to be populated manually with the routes to the other LANs, which, contrary to the main table, aren't added automatically.

before:

```
# ip route get 192.168.10.3 from 192.168.5.2 iif br-VLAN5
192.168.10.3 from 192.168.5.2 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1.2 table 10 
    cache  iif br-VLAN5
```

fix:

```
# ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 dev br-VLAN10 table 10
```

after:

```
# ip route get 192.168.10.3 from 192.168.5.2 iif br-VLAN5
192.168.10.3 from 192.168.5.2 dev br-VLAN10 table 10 
    cache  iif br-VLAN5
```

- For the first minor issue: having to add an ip rule for every single IP used from VLAN5

Normally there's no reason to use one rule per single IP from VLAN5 and this should be enough:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.5.0/24 table 10
```

But because OP made a comment telling it doesn't work when `192.168.5.1` is included, I can only say perhaps something else is interfering (other network configurations not shown, including iptables). There's still simplification possible (command `netmask 192.168.5.2:192.168.5.255` gives "only": `192.168.5.2/31 192.168.5.4/30 192.168.5.8/29 192.168.5.16/28 192.168.5.32/27 192.168.5.64/26 192.168.5.128/25`).

Comment: will do, i wanted to reply fully but as i hit enter it posted the comment.

Comment: The reason why I don’t have 192.168.5.0/24 because as I use this, again I get no internet on this VLAN, I assumed this was because it included the 192.168.5.1, so I then simply added entire DHCP ranger one ip at time and it worked.

Comment: As for your suggestion of, (ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 dev br-VLAN10 table 10) Thank you incredibly for this, adding this entry allows me to access/ping devices on VLAN 10 (192.168.10.0/24) from VLAN 5 (192.168.5.0/24) I cannot ping back from VLAN 10 to VLAN 5 but I am really not bothered about that as I don’t have much need for pinging/access from VLAN10 to VLAN5.

Comment: All the 10.8.0.1 and 128.0.0.0 have been added automatically by the VPN, I have not added these manually myself.

Comment: I did try once to have the rules for the VPN as you suggested but in my testing all that did was switch the problems over to VPN accessing the internet and that combined with the VPN settings made things further more complicated, hence I settled for this way.

Comment: What you have said about not being a default route, I don’t quite understand, but I am pretty certain everything from VLAN10 goes through VPN. I will see if I can do a tracert on the 2 ip’s you have given from vlan 10 and will post the results this evening.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As I said I am rather new to this, if there is anything else you would like me to try lease let me know, if I know how to I will give it a try.

Comment: If you feel what i have is fine after i post a comment this evening with the results of the 2 IP's i will accept your answer.

Comment: here are results for the two ips

Comment: Tracing route to 138.8.8.8 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.10.1
  2    16 ms    15 ms    14 ms  10.8.0.1
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7  rt0-cr.ldn.as200039.net [77.81.191.1]  reports: Destination net unreachable.

Comment: Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.10.1
  2    25 ms    25 ms    15 ms  10.8.0.1
  3    14 ms    15 ms    15 ms  rt0-cr.ldn.as200039.net [77.81.191.1]
  4    14 ms    15 ms    21 ms  ae20.rt0.cr.as25369.net [217.146.94.188]
  5    15 ms    17 ms    14 ms  ae0.rt0.thn.bandwidth.co.uk [5.226.136.28]
  6    15 ms    16 ms    14 ms  195.66.224.125
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12    26 ms    26 ms    34 ms  google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
Trace complete.

Comment: About the "default route", forget it, I just saw now that the 2nd part 128.0.0.0/1 was already in your routing tables (relieved). Sorry for the false alarm (I didn't copy all the configuration to do route "tests" )

Comment: thank you for your help i have accepted your solution. not too worried about being able to ping from VLAN10 to VLAN5. thank you for all your help, i had been looking for a solution for weeks.